# how to customize the Oauth refresh token in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to add more custom fields in the refresh token

[image: added]

the left side was the access token data right side was the token refresh data I need the same as the access token

Comment: Why? With the refresh tolen you get a new access token, so you get the information anyway.

Comment: no the access token is customized for the first time of creation when I use a refresh token to generate an access token it will not available because refresh token I didn't customized

Comment: Why is your access token different the second time? It should always contain the same information.

Comment: as of my understand like this second-time refresh token gives the info to generate the access not the user what is present in the refresh token it will copy the info and generate new access token

Comment: That is the identity token of OIDC. The access token doesn't contain user information. Also the refresh token doesn't contain user information. You should save the user information after you get the identity token.

Comment: https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

Comment: thanks @dur for ur info I got the idea to customize